# Error while running the App for the first time can not cast issue

Tags: android, fatal-error, classcastexception, runtimeexception

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: de.mywoofi.app, PID: 17970 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application de.mywoofi.app.MyWoofiApplication_: java.lang.ClassCastException: de.mywoofi.app.MyWoofiApplication_ cannot be cast to android.app.Application at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1069) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: de.mywoofi.app.MyWoofiApplication_ cannot be cast to android.app.Application at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50) at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:49) at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120) at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1061) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)`

The Problem is, that I have no idea, what the exact solution is.
I've tried a lot of "solutions" from this page, but maybe I'm to stupid to resolve that problem.
If there are any request for some Code, please ask.

Thanks for your help!

The requested Class (shortened)

```
@EActivity(de.mywoofi.app.R.layout.activity_main)
public class MyWoofiApplication extends Activity
{ [...]
}
```

And the cast:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyWoofiApplication_"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Full"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My updated Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationClass"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Full"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

here my ApplicationClass.java

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you didn't have your main class implement Application, but we can't say for sure without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Please share MyWoofiApplication class. And also share where your casting it to Application.

Comment: @SachinSingh I edit my Post

Comment: @svansolo refering this update code i think have no error in code. remove old code from question and put also your activity here.

Comment: @InsaneCat yes you are right, i moved it to the right direction now. Thanks!

Comment: yeah. can you redirect to application class from manifest file's allpication class to your Application.java try to Ctrl+Click on .ApplicationClass

Comment: Catch you later have a meeting ok. you are in a right direction now.

Comment: I redirected it manually but I know the shortcut :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Application need to extends Application and mentioned in Manifest file
>   &   MainActivity extends Activity

You got error because **your MyWoofiApplication_ is not extend Application it's extend Activity** so got that's why you got this error:

```
de.mywoofi.app.MyWoofiApplication_ cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

**Application Class**

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
    }
}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
    }
 }
```

Hope you understand now and it may help to you.

Comment: Happy to help you @svansolo

Comment: The solutions works, I got another error but it didn't looks like it's because of your solution. :)

Comment: Unable to instantiate application de.mywoofi.app.ApplicationClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.mywoofi.app.ApplicationClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.mywoofi.app-jkfHOG3ES5f39Hv70Dt8mw==/base.apk"

Comment: Only Register Activities in Manifest file. Application class only write in Manifist file like :  <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"

Comment: .ClassNotFoundException Exception arrise when you did not register your Activity in Manifest file see my Example 1 > SplashActivity and 2> MainActivity.

Comment: It's up to date - <application android.../> with ApplicationClass is avaliable as well, the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In android name - In Manifest.xml, you have this `MyWoofiApplication_` but you need only this `MyWoofiApplication` am I right?

Answer (score 0):

you have this line in manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyWoofiApplication_"
```

so `MyWoofiApplication_` should extends `android.app.Application` but it did not so you have this exception:

```
de.mywoofi.app.MyWoofiApplication_ cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

MyWoofiApplication_ is extending Activity so you can not cast it to Application.

You can remove **android:name=".MyWoofiApplication_"** from your application tag to resolve your issue.

Comment: If you need to use your Application class then you need to follow my Answer. this is not a proper solution.